# Windows Phone 8.1 Store app - Link to store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

In Windows 8.1 Apps we can link to store apps using ms-windows-store protocol.

```
var storeURI = new Uri("ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=<package family name>");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(storeURI);
```

Is there any similar ways in Windows Phone 8.1? I prefer not to link to the webpage of the app on the store (http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=appGUID) which then opens the app in the store. I want to directly open the app in the store.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1, We can use ms-windows-store protocol to link to the store.

***To detail page:***

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:navigate?appid={0}", appid));
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

***To review page:***

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid={0}", appid));
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

***To search page:***

```
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(@"ms-windows-store:search?keyword={0}",keyword));
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Comment: I get access denied exeption

Comment: Try using direct link explained here:
[URI schemes for launching built-in apps for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx). It works for me using URI as `zune:navigate?appid=[app ID]`

Comment: Iam  getting "This  Item not  available  on  store "please help                                           var appid = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId;   Im passing  the  app  id

Comment: You should pass the app id in the dev center.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `MarketplaceDetailTask` and open the page from the app store for the app:

```
var marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask(); 
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "<GUID of the app>"; // optional
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```

You can optionally specify which app you want to open, default is the current app.

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacedetailtask(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Seems alright, but does it work for non-Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 apps too? If so, how can I use it? I can't find it in my references.

Comment: the msdn link above says it is compatible with all versions between 7.0 and 8.1

Comment: I found it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx that it works in "Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 | Windows Phone OS 7.1" so apparently does not work in Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight)

Comment: This is the only way that works for me (WP8.0 app on WP8.1 device).

To clear it up a bit, the ContentIdentifier attribute is **not** GUID from project Assembly information in Visual Studio **nor** Product ID from WMAppManifest.xaml.

The **correct value** is the one you can found in your app listing in Windows Phone Dashboard, under App Management > App Identity (it has the form of a GUID).

Comment: Applying  above  code ,this  item  not  available  in  store.

Answer (score -1):

```
 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
          new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=723e25d1-a0ee-4824-b389-XXXXXX"));
```